# How to find the expected value of this game?

Tags: probability, statistics

How can I create a function that figures out the expected value for a value that can change.

Example:

I can flip a (fair) coin $n$ number of times.
The pot starts at $\$1$.

If I lose, $50$ cents is added to the pot.
If I win, I take what is in the pot and the pot is reset to $\$1$.

How can I figure out my expected value over $n$ number of coin flips?

The best I have come up with so far is:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n ((\text{currentPot} + (\text{incrmntOnLoss} \cdot \text{ numOfLosses})) \cdot \text{winChance})$$

but this doesn't take into account that the value can reset to $\$1$ after any flip.

It seems to be me that it would be some sort of recursive solution, but I'm unsure how that would be solved in math form

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Could be posted on Cross Validated.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/118037/can-mathematica-help-me-win-my-on-line-game?noredirect=1#comment319053_118037

quite similar question still

Comment: @Wjx that is actually the inspiration for this question. However I want to know if it is possible to solve the EV without using simulation or a lookup table

Comment: look up table can be done by computer~

Comment: I cleaned up the LaTeX a little bit and also changed $x$ to $n$. (There is no especially good reason for that, $x$ is perfectly fine, but $n$ is more commonly used when talking about natural numbers. Hope that does not bother you :-) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $e_{n, p}$ be the expected value over $n$ coin flips if the initial value of the pot is $p$.

$e_{1,p}$ is easy to calculate; $$e_{1,p} = \frac 12 \cdot p = \frac p2$$

Now given the independence of different flips, we can write in general

$$e_{n,p} = \frac 12(p + e_{n-1, 1}) + \frac 12 e_{n-1, p+1/2}$$

Using this we write out the first few terms:

$$e_{2,p} = \frac 12 \cdot (p + e_{1,1}) + \frac 12 \cdot (e_{1,p+1/2}) = p/2 + 1/4 + p/4 + 1/8 = \frac 34p + \frac 38$$
$$e_{3,p} = \frac 12 (p + e_{2,1}) + \frac 12 e_{2,p + 1/2} = p/2 + 9/16 + 3/8p + 3/16 + 3/16 = \frac 78 p + \frac{15}{16}$$
$$e_{4,p} = \frac 12 (p + e_{3,1}) + \frac 12e_{3,p + 1/2} = p/2 + 7/16  + 15/32 + 7/16p + 7/32 + 15/32 =\frac{15}{16}p + \frac{51}{32}$$

This strongly suggests that the solution is in the form

$$e_{n,p} = \frac{2^n - 1}{2^n}p + \frac{\alpha_n}{2^{n+1}}$$

Who is $\alpha_n$ though? Since it looks too hard to guess, we just plug it in the general recurrence relation to find that $\alpha_n$ must satisfy

$$\alpha_n = 2\alpha_{n-1} + 2^n + 2^{n-1} - 3$$

The general solution is $\alpha_n = 2^{n-1}(c + 3n - 6) + 3$ and since $a_2 = 3$ we get $c = 0$. So in the end $\alpha_n = 2^{n-1}(3n - 6) + 3$ and our general solution is in the form

$$e_{n,p} = \frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n}p + \frac{2^{n-1}(3n - 6) + 3}{2^{n+1}}$$

You are interested in $p=1$, so the solution is

$$e_{n,1} = \frac{2^{n}-1}{2^n} + \frac{2^{n-1}(3n - 6) + 3}{2^{n+1}}$$

Comment: +1 Irritating, I was just checking my solution when yours came up!

Comment: @almagest Ahah yeah I hate it when that happens! You could post it nonetheless, I'd be interested in discovering other solution other than this one that feels a little clumsy :)

Comment: It adds nothing to your solution. My approach was almost exactly the same, I calculated a few terms, noticed the pattern for the $p$ term, and then got a recurrence for the other term.

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you very much. My only question is, how would you generalize this a bit more? For example, if you were rolling a 6 sided die instead of a flipping a coin (or more generally, you have x% chance of winning).

Comment: @yitzih well at this point the recurrence looks like ($q$ is the probability of winning) $e_{n,p} = q(p + e_{n-1, 1}) + (1-q) e_{n-1, p+1/2}$. The solution is probably again a linear function of $p$, that is $e_{n,p} = p \beta_n + \alpha_n$. Substitute in the recurrence relation and this time you should find two recurrence relation, one for $\alpha_n$ and one for $\beta_n$. Solving them using standard method would yield the answer. (I am not sure if this works but I cannot think of a reason why it wouldn't. Calculations are probably going to be ugly though)